# Selecting records based on condition that certain records do not exist

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am working on a chat application built in Rails. To show a list of recent chats I am doing this:

```
chats = Chat.where(user_to_id: params[:user_id]).select(:user_from_id).distinct
```

What this does is pulls the user_from_id from the chats table where user_to_id is the current user.

The issue is that this will only show chats where the user that this person has chatted has responded.

I need to alter this query, or write a new query that also pulls chat records even if there is no response from the other person. Any thoughts here?

Comment: How is a chat response indicated in the table? Perhaps you could rephrase this in a more generic way, e.g. "I want to retrieve records where the user_from_id is NULL"

Comment: Perhaps you are also looking for records where `user_from_id` is the current user?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a left outer join starting from the user table.  This will include the User record regardless of if there is a Chat record.

The code would be roughly:

```
User.joins("left out join chats on (users.id = chats.user_to_id)").where("users.id = ?", params[:user_id])
```

However, I think it may be easier to just setup a has_many :incoming_chats on the User model using something like:

```
has_many :incoming_chats, foreign_key: "user_to_id"
```

Then you can just find your current user, and get their incoming chats:

```
User.find(params[:user_id]).incoming_chats
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all chat with `user_to_id` or `user_from_id`, and get the other value:

```
User.select("IF(user_to_id = #{params[:user_id]}, user_from_id, user_to_id) user_id").where('user_from_id = :u_id OR user_to_id = :u_id', u_id: params[:user_id]).distinct
```

If you want, you can be a little smarter, and select all users(from & to) and remove your id after query.